# How do I separate model and view in ipywidgets?

Tags: python, model-view-controller, ipywidgets, enaml

Consider the example of a simple foreign exchange calculator app.

I can define my model using `traitlets`:

```
from traitlets import HasTraits, Float, observe, Enum
import math

class FXModel(HasTraits):
    domestic_qty = Float()
    foreign_qty = Float()
    fx_rate  = Float(float('nan')) # in units of domestic_qty/foreign_qty
    lock = Enum(['domestic', 'foreign'], default_value='domestic')
    _calculating = Enum([None, 'domestic', 'foreign'], default_value=None)

    def calc_foreign(self):
        if not math.isnan(self.fx_rate):
            self._calculating = 'foreign'
            self.foreign_qty = self.domestic_qty / self.fx_rate
            self._calculating = None

    def calc_domestic(self):
        if not math.isnan(self.fx_rate):
            self._calculating = 'domestic'
            self.domestic_qty = self.foreign_qty * self.fx_rate
            self._calculating = None

    @observe('domestic_qty')
    def on_domestic(self, change):
        if self._calculating is None:
            self.calc_foreign()

    @observe('foreign_qty')
    def on_foreign(self, change):
        if self._calculating is None:
            self.calc_domestic()

    @observe('fx_rate')
    def on_fxrate(self, change):
        if self.lock == 'domestic':
            self.calc_foreign()
        else:
            self.calc_domestic()
```

And a corresponding simple "print" based view:

```
class FXView:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model

    def show(self):
        print("""
        domestic_qty: {:.4g}
        foreign_qty:  {:.4g}
        fx_rate:      {:.4g}
        lock:         {}""".format(
            self.model.domestic_qty,
            self.model.foreign_qty,
            self.model.fx_rate,
            self.model.lock
        ))
```

Here's how it works:

```
>> fx_model = FXModel(domestic_qty = 100., fx_rate = 200.)
>> fx_view = FXView(fx_model)
>> fx_view.show()
    domestic_qty: 100
    foreign_qty:  0.5
    fx_rate:      200
    lock:         domestic
>> fx_model.fx_rate = 195.
>> fx_view.show()
    domestic_qty: 100
    foreign_qty:  0.5128
    fx_rate:      195
    lock:         domestic
```

I have also created a view using ipywidgets:

```
import ipywidgets as widgets
domestic_label = widgets.Label("Domestic quantity")
domestic_field = widgets.FloatText()

foreign_label = widgets.Label("Foreign quantity")
foreign_field = widgets.FloatText()

fx_label = widgets.Label("Exchange rate (domestic/foreign)")
fx_field = widgets.FloatText()

lock_label = widgets.Label("If rates change, keep ")
lock_field = widgets.Dropdown(options=["domestic", "foreign"])
lock_label_post = widgets.Label('fixed')

ipyview = widgets.HBox([widgets.VBox([domestic_label, foreign_label, fx_label, lock_label]),
              widgets.VBox([domestic_field, foreign_field, fx_field, widgets.HBox([lock_field, lock_label_post])])])
```

It looks really good:

[image]

My question is; how can I "bind" my model and my ipyview together? I have some experience with `enaml` where this is possible via the operator `:=` and friends.

What's the best way of doing this with `ipywidgets`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Great question! I posted an answer in an ipywidgets issue: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2296

So here's how to make a custom view using ipywidget views, using the widgets from the post. The key is the link calls to bind attributes to widget values.

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
from traitlets import link
from IPython.display import display

class FXWidgetView:
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
        self.domestic_label = widgets.Label("Domestic quantity")
        self.domestic_field = widgets.FloatText()

        self.foreign_label = widgets.Label("Foreign quantity")
        self.foreign_field = widgets.FloatText()

        self.fx_label = widgets.Label("Exchange rate (domestic/foreign)")
        self.fx_field = widgets.FloatText()

        self.lock_label = widgets.Label("If rates change, keep ")
        self.lock_field = widgets.Dropdown(options=["domestic", "foreign"])
        self.lock_label_post = widgets.Label('fixed')

        self.ipyview = widgets.HBox([widgets.VBox([self.domestic_label, self.foreign_label, self.fx_label, self.lock_label]),
                      widgets.VBox([self.domestic_field, self.foreign_field, self.fx_field, widgets.HBox([self.lock_field, self.lock_label_post])])])

        link((model, 'domestic_qty'), (self.domestic_field, 'value'))
        link((model, 'foreign_qty'), (self.foreign_field, 'value'))
        link((model, 'fx_rate'), (self.fx_field, 'value'))
        link((model, 'lock'), (self.lock_field, 'value'))

    def _ipython_display_(self):
        display(self.ipyview)
```

I'll point out that Param has been advocating this sort of separation for a while, and @jbednar has pointed out that ipywidgets could implement convenience functions to support this pattern as well. I think that's a good idea - to have some simple convenience functions that are a step up from the interact functions that take a HasTraits class, introspect it, and provide default widgets for different traits for common cases.

Comment: I've copied it over